# ASP.NET WebPages Service or WCF and WebPages website

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WebPages website (ASP.NET WebPages) using Razor syntax and C#. And I need a web service so I can expose it to a Metro app.

But how can I have a WCF service work alongside my ASP.NET Web Pages website? Do I just open up my website in Visual Studio, and then right-click Project and Add new Project > WCF Service?

Are there any tutorials online for this? I cannot find the information I am looking for. Or better yet, how could I create a service using just the ASP.NET WebPages framework?

Comment: Hey.. i am not rude ..by reading your question how can anyone come to know that what you are exactly looking for and there is lots for tutorial on creating wcf service and hosting it ..first read them ..No one is going to tell you whole lot of process.

Comment: for your help you can start with :- 1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx   2)http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb386386.aspx

Comment: @Pranav I am sorry. Thank you for helping. These links are very helpful